# Reset buffer when doing benchmarks

Tags: sql-server, performance, performance-testing

We are running performance benchmarks as a part of our release pipeline and we have some problems with results being too good (2-3 times faster approx) from the sql server when running the same query over and over again.

Is there a way to flush this buffer to make the results more "real world".
We've tried using DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS, but that produces results that are way to slow when compared to real world.

The current solution to this problem is only running the queries once, but that give us alot of variation.

Comment: The "real world" is likely with a warm cache so you could discard the first execution and evaluate the subsequent runs. Be aware of the implications of [performance testing with `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`](https://www.dbdelta.com/performance-testing-with-dbcc-dropcleanbuffers/) since the storage engine behaves differently with a cold versus warm cache.

Comment: Our product runs aggregations and the users keep changing the queries so basically no query is like the other. What we've seen is in app insights is that the queries run approx 2-3 times faster in the benchmark. 
If we only run each query once we get a result that looks the like real world, but that is not ideal since we want to to run them multiple to see how much variation we have.